# Using hamcrest matchers with primitive type arrays

Tags: java, testing, hamcrest

Hamcrest works well for primitive data types due to automatic boxing and unboxing like in this case:

```
assertThat(1, is(1));
```

However, I would like to use hamcrest's `hasItemInArray` matcher with a primitive type array like this:

```
int[] values = someMethodCall();
assertThat(values, hasItemInArray(1));
```

Since there is no automatic boxing/unboxing for arrays of primitive data types the above code does not compile. Is there any preferred way of accomplishing the above, other than manually converting from `int[]` to `Integer[]`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't an automatic way of achieving this. If you can make use of 3rd party libraries you might want to check out the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library which provides an [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) class with a conversion method:

[Integer[] toObject(int[] array)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29)

```
int[] values = someMethodCall();
Integer[] objValues = ArrayUtils.toObject(values);
assertThat(objValues , hasItemInArray(1));
```

Comment: I guessed so already, but thanks for the confirmation and pointing me to Apache Commons!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution it also uses Apache Commons `ArrayUtils#toObject`

With the imports

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.toObject;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.arrayContaining;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.arrayContainingInAnyOrder;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItemInArray;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
```

You can write readable tests like

```
@Test
void primitiveArrayTest() {
    int[] actual = new int[]{1, 2, 3};

    assertThat(toObject(actual), is(arrayContaining(1, 2, 3)));
    assertThat(toObject(actual), is(arrayContainingInAnyOrder(2, 3, 1)));
    assertThat(toObject(actual), hasItemInArray(2));
    assertThat(toObject(actual), is(not(arrayContaining(-5))));
}
```

The `is` is just used to improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Yet an alternative to writing your own matcher would be to use one in a matcher library like [conmatch](https://github.com/almondtools/conmatch).

```
int[] values = someMethodCall();
assertThat(values, intArrayContaining(1));
```

I guess there are already other Matchers available on github.